# salesforce SOQL with group by (math before the group by)

Tags: salesforce, soql

I want to use math of two columns and then sum up while fetching data with the group by class in SOQL. (math should happen before the Sum).

I am trying something like this... please ignore the syntax.

"select sum(netprice), sum(listprice), sum(listprice-netprice) from Quotelines group by Product"

It gives me error. I saw there are some limitations to use group by query. please help me to come out with a solution

1. How to solve this query problem
2. If not by query, what could be the possible/clean solution.

Note: Customer may have 50k to 10k products.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make a new field on QuoteLineItem, type formula(number) (or maybe formula(currency)?), put your calculation in there and select this field in the query. It's bit wasteful to have a field just for 1 query though. Your call, will you use it in some other places (listviews? reports? although reports can do some basic formulas on the fly) or is it better to calculate in the application that sends this query.